# get checked values in a pdf file

Tags: pdf, checkbox, data-mining, data-extraction

I am having some troubles extracting some informations from pdf files with checkboxes.
I would like to get the value next to checked box.
Do anyone have an idea how I can solve this problem please ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fRna.png)

Comment: Indeed, you appear to have an application already which mostly works and merely has issues where check boxes are involved. Which is your runtime environment? Do you use some PDF library? Which one? Are those checkboxes form field widgets? ...

Comment: I have tested many libraries like PyPDF2, openCV, pdftablextract. I tried to see if i can get fields with PyPDF2 but i got None. I am just trying to find out if someone has encountred this case before. I am working in Jupyter notebook

Comment: Then please share the pdf in question. There are many ways to show check boxes in a pdf...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.